# Find the GS of the DE :$y(\cos x+ \ln y)+(x+ye^y)y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the GS of the DE :$y(\cos x+ \ln y)+(x+ye^y)y'=0$

My attempt:

since given equation is not because $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$

wherer $M=y(\cos x+ \ln y), N=x+ye^y$

when  i tried to find integrating factor i am not getting any hint please

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A little hint***

$$y(\cos x+ \ln y)+(x+ye^y)y'=0$$
$$y(\cos x+ \ln y)=-(x+ye^y)y'$$
$$(\cos x+ \ln y)=- \frac {(x+ye^y)y'} y$$
$$\frac {(\cos x+ \ln y)}{y'}=- \frac {(x+ye^y)} y$$
$$\frac {dx}{dy}(\cos x+ \ln y)=- \frac {(x+ye^y)} y$$
$$x'(\cos x+ \ln y)=-\frac {(x+ye^y)} y$$
$$(\sin(x))'+x'\ln y + \frac xy=-e^y$$
$$(\sin(x))'+(x\ln y)'=-e^y$$
$$\dfrac {d(\sin(x)+x\ln y)}{dy}=-e^y$$

Simply integrate now.....
$$\sin(x)+ x\ln y=-\int e^y dy+K$$
$$\boxed {\sin(x)+ x\ln y=-e^y+K}$$
$$........$$